# website panel installation error

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am installing website panel by web Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.0 but after installing website panel and going to website panel url it shows error that:-

Thanks Zinm3r you were right but now on opening the web site panel i got error:-Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
specific error details below and modify your configuration file
appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.web.extensions.

Source Error:

Line 7:      
Line 8:    
Line 9:    
Line 10:     
Line 11:

Source File: C:\WebsitePanel\Portal\web.config    Line: 9

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

Comment: Additional details needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before, I think WebsitePanel 1.2 is no longer supported. Try installing WebsitePanel using [this installer](http://www.websitepanel.net/downloads/) which worked perfectly fine for me.

Edit: Choose Standalone mode in WebsitePanel installation process.

Comment: Ok i will try it jake and update you

Comment: I got an error in the final step that is got an error :- website panel enterprise server error the windows account is alr.    sorry i could read till here only coz the rest of error was hidden.

Comment: Alright, Go to server manager, under `Configuration` browse `Local Users and Groups` then open `User`. In right pane if you see any user related to WebsitePanel (WP*) remove it and Try again.

Comment: Thanks Zinm3r you were right but now on opening the web site panel i got error:-shown above in my edited question.

Comment: Cool, Run this: `aspnet_regiis -c`

Comment: I have to run in this powershell or somewhere else?

Comment: +1, You are quite welcome.